Referencing an input with a label by aria-labelledby
If I have an input with its aria-label set to 1 and an associated label set to 2, what will be calculated as aria label of an element, referencing the input?
<input type="radio" id="cpp-search-video-btn" aria-label="1" role="tab">
<label for="cpp-search-video-btn" aria-hidden="true">2</label>
<div id="cpp-search-video-tab" aria-labelledby="cpp-search-video-btn" role="tabpanel">…</div>

What's the aria label of the div#cpp-search-video-tab: 1, 2, or, maybe, unset? (I want it to be "1").
As far as I see, there is no information on substitutions at MDN.

Hello @isherwood, please take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/. You will see that all tabpanel <div>s do have aria labels, defined by aria-labelledby. I'm doing exactly the same, but instead of the <button> as a tab I have an <input>. And since my input label doesn't contain anything but SVG, I want the tabpanel aria label to be defined by aria-label in the <input>.

The answer is indeed 1. ATtribute aria-labelledby has priority over aria-label, which itself has priority over <label>. See MDN

If an element has both attributes set, aria-labelledby will be used. aria-labelledby takes precedence over all other methods of providing an accessible name, including aria-label, <label>, and the element's inner text.

However, if I can add another comment on your code:
<input type="radio" id="cpp-search-video-btn" aria-label="1" role="tab">
<label for="cpp-search-video-btn" aria-hidden="true">2</label>

It would be better to avoid using aria-hidden and ARIA at all if possible. The following code would be qualitatively better as pair the first rule of ARIA: don't use it, unless you really need.
<input type="radio" id="cpp-search-video-btn" role="tab">
<label for="cpp-search-video-btn">1</label>

Or maybe at least:
<input type="radio" id="cpp-search-video-btn" role="tab">
<label for="cpp-search-video-btn"><span class="sr_only">1</span><span aria-hidden="true">2</span></label>

More generally, if you have a real <label>, there shouldn't  be any need to override it with aria-label. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense to have the <label> at the first place.

Hello QuentinC, thank you for the answer! Since I wasn't much into accessibility, I copied patterns from here and there. As far a I remember, this one was from Bootstrap, but now I cannot find it, so maybe I'm wrong. Unfortunately it's not that simple: my <label> contains no text, but SVG. That's why I really need aria-label for the input. Should I omit aria-hidden="true" for a <label> with just SVG within?

With an image inside the label, you have two options: add a proper alt text to the image and don't use any ARIA at all, or take my last example using sr_only+aria-hidden technique. The alt text is normally much better and simpler, except if your SVG is inline, in which case I think it isn't well supported everywhere (I'm maybe not up to date with inline SVG, maybe it's all fine now, it should be tested again to be sure)

Thank you again. It seems like alt is not supported for inline SVG, and yep, I prefer creating a vector library using a root <svg><defs> element with <symbol>s + <svg><use></use></svg> in place.

Note that for inline SVG, there isn't an alt attribute, but there's a <title> subtag instead. However, as far as I know, all screen readers don't support it always very well (but what I read about that has already several years, so maybe it's no longer true, maybe it's all fine now; it should be tested again and updated)

Well, if I get it right and “Accessibility” pane in DevTools shows the aria label in the “Computed Properties” → “Name” section, the answer is “1”.
